# 'uable to open read only database' while deploying django cms in cPanel server

Tags: sqlite, cpanel, mod-wsgi

I already deployed a django cms in my cPanel server using (mod_wsgi), But it showing 500 internal server error. 'unable to open a read only database' (default sqllite). Any one know how to resolve it.

Comment: What OS is the server running? If you're on a cPanel server, do you manage the server?

Comment: CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
Yes i have the root permission.

Comment: I assume you've given ownership of the directory & db file to whichever user/group runs apache? e.g. `chown apache:apache /srv/mysite/DATABASE.sqlite`